# Show layout on top of other pages and have it never close, even when contentpage changes

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve a layout that sits on top of all the other content views. And even when you navigate away from the current `ContentView` have the main layout remain on its position. I tried achieving this simply by showing a content view on top not in full screen, but even when I set a height property to the `ContentView` it will always display full screen.

So I decided to make three grids, two of which transparent and one with a solid background color.
Using the PopUp Plugin, this seemed to worked, however now you cannot click anything on the underlying content page because the transparent grid is still blocking the click.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Green">

    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

How would I go on about this?
I am fine with using a third party library.

Comment: The popup concept is like modal dialog pages, it's not supposed to allow click outside, the only case is going to dismiss it, you probably don't want to use a popup for your requirement check https://stackoverflow.com/q/64548271 especially that you want it to persist across pages not sure  popup could provide that.

Comment: It does actually persist across multiple pages. Your solution is android nativ, but it is close to what I want. Maybe there isnt anything avaiblable yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the RG PopUp PlugIn this is achievable like so:

```
<pages:PopupPage  
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             HeightRequest="200"
            BackgroundColor="#00000000"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
    InputTransparent="True"
             x:Class="InteriorCircle.Pages.PopUps.PopUp_FloatingInfo">

        

    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation DurationIn="400"
                                   DurationOut="300"
                                   EasingIn="SinOut"
                                   EasingOut="SinIn"
                                   HasBackgroundAnimation="True"
                                   PositionIn="Center"
                                   PositionOut="Center"
                                   ScaleIn="1.2"
                                   ScaleOut="0.8" />
    </pages:PopupPage.Animation>


    <!-- takes whole page, so upper and lower grid are just to leave parts transparent-->
    <Grid >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <Grid Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  InputTransparent="true" >

        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="20"/>
            


        </Grid>


    </Grid>

</pages:PopupPage>
```

Comment: In 2 days I can, yes ;)