# Xamarin Forms application with half of screen size

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to create a xamarin forms application that will work on half of the screen. As default, layouts fill the screen. How could i do this by layout or contentView or ContentPage?

Comment: You can't.  XF pages are intended to fill the device screen.  What is the use case you're trying to fulfill?

Comment: Trying to write a helper app which will take screenshot or screen recorder of active screen... For that reason don't wanna fill the screen with my app...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin forms don't have this kind of function(half screen)

Although there a thing called widget on android,**Android Floating Widget** is nothing but overlay views drawn over applications. To allow drawing views over other applications.you can refer to here to know more https://www.journaldev.com/14673/android-floating-widget

and here is a related queston with the working solution:[How can I do this floating action button where can run even in background mode in Xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548271/how-can-i-do-this-floating-action-button-where-can-run-even-in-background-mode-i)